# Hyphenation command doesn't print

Tags: hyphenation

I am having problems during the writing of my thesis. Everytime I use `\hyphenation` to split a ward so that it goes on a new line rather than going out of the margins, that words disappear instead.

An example is:

```
In addition, mechanistically more challenging transformations have 
\hyphenation{be-en} extensively studied in recent years, including 
NHC-catalyzed transformation
```

[image]

As you can see, the "been" is missing.

I have nothing specified in the preamble.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: How are you using `\hyphenation`? Are you aware that it is meant to be used in the *preamble* to tell TeX where it is allowed to hyphenate certain words with which it needs help?

Comment: No, I did not know.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a Minimum (non)Working Example of your problem. Just giving us a long list of packages (most of which are probably irrelevant to the problem) and saying "I did something, but it doesn't work" is not very useful.

Comment: @GiovanniDiMauro Within the document you can put `\-` where you want to allow a word to be hyphenated…

Comment: as noted above `\hyphenation` is being misused here but also the default rules for english do not break been as be-en with good reason, the break there would be so bad as to render it almost unreadable, surely you can break somewere else even if it causes some space to stretch.

Comment: at last I opted for the \- and it worked just fine. thanks a lot.

Comment: Hyphenating `be-en` is utterly wrong, I'm afraid. It would be like hyphenating `pi-anura` in Italian: a diphthong is never split.

Comment: it works for tex but your readers will not thank you for writing `be\-en`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\hyphenation` is a declaration to be used in the preamble that declares how *automatic* hyphenation should work on a particular word so

```
\hyphenation{trans-for-ma-tions}
```

for example would specify the places TeX could break `transformations` (this is actually the default in this case).

For one-off discretionary hyphen within the body of the document you can use `\-` but it would be very wrong to hyphenate `been`.

You hadn't provided a real example but I assume that your case is like this with an overfull box:

```
Overfull \hbox (2.73953pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--11
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 In ad-di-tion, mech-a-nis-ti-cally more chal-leng-ing trans-f
or-ma-tions have been
```

[image]

From the input

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\addtolength\textwidth{-23.1pt}

\begin{document}

Zzzzzz\dotfill zzzz

In addition, mechanistically more challenging transformations have 
been extensively studied in recent years, including 
NHC-catalyzed transformation

Zzzzzz\dotfill zzzz
\end{document}
```

Changing `been` to `be\-en` would remove the warning at the cost of making the text much harder to read.  There are much better alternatives, for example if you add

```
\usepackage{microtype}
```

then not only does the overfull box go, so does the slightly ugly short final line of the paragraph with just the `tion` from the end of `transformation`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\addtolength\textwidth{-23.1pt}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}

Zzzzzz\dotfill zzzz

In addition, mechanistically more challenging transformations have 
been extensively studied in recent years, including 
NHC-catalyzed transformation

Zzzzzz\dotfill zzzz
\end{document}
```